# I cant center and stack my (HTML + CSS) atom logo

Tags: html, css

I can't center my atom animation logo, or stack it by using `position:absolute`. I also want it to be centered and it's not working.

**GOAL:** Stack the logo + center it over the particle.js divider

I am using particles.js for the background.

Here is the site:
http://www.niitro.ga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the following CSS to your `.box` element:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
```

Answer (score 0):

to the div with class='box' add the following style:

```
<div class='box' style="left: calc(50% - 150px);top: calc(50% - 150px); >
```